# Value conversion in view causes error in subsequent query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, type-conversion

I am using SQL Server 2005 with the view that goes like this:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.DLS_VPBX_tenant 
AS 
    SELECT 
        custid, 
        crid, 
        tenantid, 
        CONVERT(int, name) AS name, 
        users, 
        status, 
        updated, 
        mirror_exts, 
        domesticdids, 
        tollfreedids, 
        faxdids, 
        dids 
    FROM 
        DLS_PBX_tenant 
    WHERE 
        ISNUMERIC(name) = 1
```

However, when I run a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM dls_vpbx_tenant 
WHERE name = 39605
```

I get this error:

> Initializing connection... Connection ready. Took 0.056 seconds.
>
> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9223372036854775807
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '_1135see' to data type int.
> Statement completed successfully. (0 results). 0.000 seconds. (Line
> 1).
> Finished. Total time: 0.056 seconds.

What am I doing wrong and what would be the right way to handle this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try adding a `CASE` expression as the view column expression: `CASE WHEN isnumeric(name) = 1 THEN convert(int,name) END as name`. If you were using a supported SQL Server version, `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` would be other options.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dan. Adding that CASE statement did it. Could you please, explain, what I was doing wrong? Why did it not work with my filter?

Comment: SQL Server can end up initially attempting to evaluate more rows than will ultimately be returned - due to however it determines is the optimal way to retrieve the data - hence any bad data can result in this sort of issue.

Comment: @SamRozenfeld, if you look at the original execution plan, you'll probably see the conversion in the plan before the isnumeric expression is evaluated. Remember that SQL is declarative so the optimizer may evaluate expressions in a different order for efficiency. The `CASE` expression, however, controls the order.